# Can one add a payment ID to a subaddress in Monero?

Tags: transaction-data, payment-id, sub-address

Is it possible to add a payment ID to a sub address in Monero? How can this be done? Or is payment id's completely phased out and shouldn't be used at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible (well, you could do it manually but no wallet would recognize them).